# Is it possible to connect to the Azure App Service windows machine with RD?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have an App Service in my Azure resource group. My ASP NET application is hosted on the windows environment inside that app service. I am wondering if it is possible to connect to this desktop windows server using Remote Desktop or something like this. There is a KUDU feature on the Azure but the only one thing that I can do with this is to show server's CMD. That is not enough, because I need to access to the windows desktop GUI like on typical PC. Do you know any tool that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

App Service runs your applications in a sandbox and it's simply not possible to remote desktop to the underlying VM. There's no Windows GUI that you can access.

The Virtual Machines service allow full control of the VM and you can access the Windows GUI using remote desktop.